# How to search text or find text from chat of particular contact in skype latest version (8.12)?

Tags: search, skype

Any one know that how can I search for particular text in chat in newer version of skype(8.12)?

I know that I can search in particular text in older version of skype.

But now in latest version of skype it's difficult to search in particular contact because there isn't any option there is only **global search option** for all the contacts.

while searching on internet they are showing older version's search option even on skype's official website the document is regarding older version.

Document Link of it's Official site :- https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA392/how-do-i-manage-my-conversation-history-in-skype-for-windows-desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Newer versions of Skype no longer offers this very useful feature.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_win10-skype_messms-skype_instamessms/searching-in-skype-conversations-ctrl-f-used-to/e4e49f36-0bdf-4634-be67-e195f8b73198), but it **is** available in "Classic Skype".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In version 8.28.0.41 you can do searching. There is an input field on top of the app which after click allows you to select where you want to search. You can then select the tab "Messages" which then will allow you to search through all your messages. Currently it's not possible to search on a per user base. But better than nothing.

Great would be a shortcut to directly jump to search however that doesn't work out of a conversation or at least I don't know how to set it up. Strg + F still works if you have no conversation open.

Answer (score 0):

You can search in a specific conversation using the the Version 8.28.0.41.

Choose the conversation you want to search, press Ctrl+F, select the option "Message" and will apear two options (All and Current).

The option **All** will search in all contacts and the option **Current** will search just in the current selected contact.

[image: Sample]